# Launching an executable file

Tags: command-line, kubuntu

I have a very noob question here. Usually when I click an executable file a small window that has 3 buttons (open, execute and cancel) would pop up, and in order to run that file I had to press execute, simple as that.

A few minutes ago I checked the `don't ask again` checkbox and then I pressed Open. Now the problem is that whenever I try to run a file it just opens in Kate (text editor) without showing that pop up window and I can't seem to find the option to execute anywhere.

Basically my question is this:
**How can I get that small pop up window back? Or is there any other way to execute those files?**

Comment: Presumably, you use Kubuntu, is that right?

Comment: @mikewhatever I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In nautilus (files) menu, open Edit > Preferences > Behaviour tab > and restore the setting for "executable text file" to "Ask each time".

Good luck!

Comment: This would work on Ubuntu, but I don't think Kubuntu uses Nautilus, does it?

Comment: You could check the preferences menu anyway. I believe there is a similar option. (I think general -> confirmations)

Comment: @E.F.Nijboer I actually installed Nautilus a few days ago (luckily :p) I followed your instructions and it worked! thanks a bunch for helping me out! :D